# System.out.println() a float value,but i get a weird result

Tags: java

```
 public class Myclass
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        float  af=5.2345556f;
        System.out.println(af);
     }
 }
```

why the result is 5.2345557 not 5.2345556?

Comment: ... because you're using `float`, which doesn't have as much precision as you're expecting. Bound to be a dupe, but I'm not sure I have the time to find it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you can't represent the value 5.2345556 exactly in bits, so an approximate value will be used. This is characteristic of floating point arithmetic

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits.
>
> In contrast, given any fixed number of bits, most calculations with
>   real numbers will produce quantities that cannot be exactly
>   represented using that many bits. Therefore the result of a
>   floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back
>   into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Comment: thanks！and i also found this [Floating_point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point),it may help understand is.